# Linq way of finding all lists with numbers going up

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have 4 lists of list

```
4,2,6,8,9 
3,2,1 
1,5,9
2,6,8,9,0
```

Is there a straightforward way in Linq to get all the lists with numbers increasing only.
I've got this working using nested for loops, but wanted to find out if there is a way to do this in linq.

### Example:

#### Input:

```
[[4,2,6,8,9]
,[3,2,1]
,[1,5,9]
,[2,6,8,9,0]]
```

#### Output:

```
[[1,5,9]]
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: ever heard of orderby?

Comment: YEs, I'll edit the question. Negative points?

Comment: @Qash: What is the not-straightforward method you using at the moment?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee How does `OrderBy` help you on it's own determine if the contents of a list are already sorted ascending? Perhaps in conjunction with something else, thus forming an answer, maybe.

Comment: Can you rewrite your example to have *Input* => **Output** form? I have no clue what you're asking here - I tried to edit in there - is this right?

Comment: `lists.Where(list=>list.SequenceEqual(list.OrderBy(x=>x)));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, there is a way:

```
yourLists
 .Where(list => list
 .Select((x, idx) => new {x, idx}).Skip(1).All(n => n.x > list[n.idx - 1]));
```

This code gets the numbers with the indices, skips the first item and then check for each number if it's bigger than the number that comes before it.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 var lst = new List<int>() { 1,5,3};
 var odr = lst.OrderBy(s => s);
 var match = lst.SequenceEqual(odr);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is none but you can make an extension method of this

```
List<int> lst = new List<int> { 1, 5, 9 };

List<int> copy = lst.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

bool isGoingUP = true;            

for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
{
    if (lst[i] != copy[i])
    {
        isGoingUP = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it really need to loop?

Comment: What do think there is some magic in LINQ which does not do loops?

Comment: I think there are large parts missing for this to be an answer - for example where is the extension method? How do you use it to solve the question?